# Spring boot edit application.properties

Tags: properties, spring-boot, persistence

Is it possible to add new `properties` to `application.properties`or overwrite existing values?

```
resource = new ClassPathResource("/application.properties");
Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
```

**Things i already tried:**

*Using `store`:*

```
props.put("spring.datasource.url", "<my value>");
prop.store(new FileOutputStream("xyz.properties"), null);
```

*Using `ConfigurableEnvironment`:*

```
   @Autowired
   ConfigurableEnvironment env;

   ...

   props.put("spring.datasource.url", "<my value>");
   environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("myProps", props));
```

Then when i use `props.get(key)` it prints the correct value, but the next time i use

```
Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
```

it isn't there.

So did i do something wrong, or is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: No you cannot. Why, well the `application.properties` is probably part of your jar and you cannot change the content of that while running the application. But why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: Inside my `properties` i have for example: `cron.expression = 0 0/7 7 * * *` which defines when a `scheduled task` executes. But i need the possibility to change the execute time(e. g. per `Rest-Api`).

Comment: With just changing the properties you aren't there. You would need to restart your application to make that possible.

Comment: OK thanks. Then I'll try to find another solution

Comment: Spring Cloud Config already has support for that...